# MacBook Pro 2017 model with non-existant upload speeds

Tags: network, wifi, performance

MacBook Pro 2017 model (model A1707) with major upload speed issues.

If I do a test from speedtest.net I get pretty decent speeds, but not quite what my ISP offers, but that's ok. I get about half download speed (500mb/s out of 940mb/s my mesh reports) but just presume that's down to Mac's capabilities. I see the full upload speed my mesh reports.

But when I go to upload files from this Mac, the speed is unusable. To upload files to Slack, YouTube, WordPress and even my NAS it sends them at about **5kb/s**!!

I've been having this issue for a couple of months now and 'm started to get very fed up.

Any tips on how I can fix this? Might I need a new network adapter?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  What about uploading from other devices on this same wifi network?  Are the speeds the same?

Comment: uploading from any other device on the network works as expected and is speedy.